# Kivy: Radio button correct implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My App has 3 screens to navigate through with the 'ActionBar'. I have named each screen in kv file, one is 'track' the other 'pess'. These are the two I need help with.

I created a radiobutton widget in my 'pess' screen class (pictures below) So I could add email address.

In my 'track' screen class I have all the data I'd like to send over email but I think I'm over complicating things. I want to link the active radiobutton from my 'pess' screen to my 'track' screen def send function...

my Main.py looks like this

```
class ScreenGenerator(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PessQuestions(Screen):
    email = {}
    path = ''

    def loadEmails(self, *args):
        self.path = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir + '/'
        try:
            with open(self.path + 'email.json', 'r') as data:
                self.email = json.load(data)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def saveEmails(self, *args):
        print(self.ids.name.text, type(self.ids.name.text))
        print(self.ids.address.text, type(self.ids.address.text))
        self.email[self.ids.name.text] = self.ids.address.text

        self.path = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir + '/'
        with open(self.path + 'email.json', 'w') as email_address_json:
            json.dump(self.email, email_address_json)
            print('saveEmails')
        self.ids.address.text = ''
        self.ids.name.text = ''

        self.ids.info.clear_widgets()
        self.on_pre_enter() # refresh screen

    def delete_email(self, check):
        address = check.ids.who_name.text
        del self.email[address]

        self.ids.info.remove_widget(check)
        self.saveEmails()

##########################################################
########### PRE ENTER ####################################
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.info.clear_widgets()
        self.loadEmails()
        try:
            for name, mail in self.email.items():
                self.ids.info.add_widget(Checkboxes(name=name, mail=mail, email=self.email))
        except ValueError:
            print('VALUE ERROR: Label.text accept only "str"')

        self.ids.pess_date.text = strftime('[b]%A[/b], %B %Y') # time and date

##########################################################
########### PRE LEAVE ####################################
    def on_pre_leave(self):
        self.ids.info.clear_widgets()
        self.saveEmails()

class Checkboxes(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, name='', mail='', email='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.who_name.text = name
        self.ids.who_email.text = mail

    def on_checkbox_Active(self, checkboxInstance, isActive):
        address = ''
        if isActive:
            '''
            Email is used for recipient
            '''
            name = self.ids.who_name.text
            email = self.ids.who_email.text
            print('Email Set!')
            return email
        else:
            '''
            Nothing happens, email is not used
            '''


##########################################################
######## TRACKERS WINDOWS ################################
##########################################################
class Trackers(Screen):
    email = {'davi': 'example@gmail.com'}
    storage = {}
    pess_storage = {}
    path = ''

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.path = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir + '/'
        self.loadData()
        for tracker, num in self.storage.items():
            self.ids.track.add_widget(Tracker(text=tracker, number=num))

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        self.ids.track.clear_widgets()
        self.saveData()

    def saveData(self, *args):
        with open(self.path + 'data.json', 'w') as data:
            json.dump(self.storage, data)

    def loadData(self, *args):
        try:
            with open(self.path + 'data.json', 'r') as data:
                self.storage = json.load(data)
                print(self.storage)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def savePESS(self, PESS):
        self.pess_storage['physical'] = PESS.ids.phy_text.text
        self.pess_storage['emotional'] = PESS.ids.emo_text.text
        self.pess_storage['spiritual'] = PESS.ids.spi_text.text
        self.pess_storage['sexual'] = PESS.ids.sex_text.text
        self.pess_storage['comment'] = PESS.ids.comment.text

    def save_text(self, tracker, text_input, *args):
        tracker.ids.label.text = text_input.text
        self.storage[text_input.text] = '0'
        self.saveData()
        self.loadData()
        print('testing')

    def send(self, PESS):
        self.path = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir + '/'
        with open(self.path + 'bat', 'r') as bat:
            login = bat.read()
            davi = self.email['davi']
            mail = PESS.ids.who_email.text
            #kevin = self.email['kevin'] # instead of this I'd like to have this variable linked to 
            gmail = GMail(davi, login)

            day = strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y")
            tracker_message = 'PESS\n'
            subject_message = f"Subject: PESS {day}"

            for pess, txt in self.pess_storage.items():
                tracker_message += f"\t{pess.title()}: {txt}\n"

            for tracker, numbers in self.storage.items():
                tracker_message += f"\n{numbers} ---> {tracker}\n"

            message = f"{subject_message}\n\n{tracker_message}"
            msg = Message(f'PESS | {day}', to=mail, text=message)
            gmail.send(msg)

            self.sent_confirmation(f'{self.ids.who_name.text}: {mail}')

    def sent_confirmation(self, recipient):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=40, spacing=5)
        pop = Popup(title='Email Sent', content=box, size_hint=(None,None), size=(self.width, self.width/2))
        info = Label(text=f'Congrats, {recipient} has recieved an email.')
        box.add_widget(info)
        pop.open()
        self.saveData()


class Tracker(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, text='', number='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = text
        self.ids.count_add.text = number


class Pess(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#262829')

        return ScreenGenerator()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pess().run()
```

kv file

```
#: import rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#: import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox
<Label>:
    font_size: '17dp'

<MenuButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.height, self.height
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.x + self.width - self.height, self.y
            size: self.height, self.height
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x + self.height / 2, self.y
            size: self.width - self.height, self.height

<RoundButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.width / 2.265, self.y + 130
            size: self.height - self.height / 1.5, self.height / 3

<MenuButton2@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.height, self.height
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.x + self.width - self.height, self.y
            size: self.height, self.height
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x + self.height / 2, self.y
            size: self.width - self.height, self.height

<FloatButton@ButtonBehavior+FloatLayout>:
    id: float_root
    size_hint: (None, None)
    text: '[b]+[/b]'
    font_size: '48dp'
    btn_size: (140,140)
    size: (140,140)
    bg_color: (0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 1)
    pos_hint: {'x': 5.4, 'y': .17}
    Button:
        text: float_root.text
        font_size: '14dp'
        #allow_stretch: True
        markup: True
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: float_root.btn_size
        pos_hint: float_root.pos_hint
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (0,1,0,0)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: float_root.bg_color
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

<TrackerButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0


<ScreenGenerator>:
    Menu:
        name: 'menu'
    Trackers:
        name: 'track'
    PessQuestions:
        name: 'pess'

<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 30
        Image:
            source: 'book.png'
            allow_strech: True
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color: 
                    rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 1
        MenuButton:
            text: 'Enter Trackers'
            height: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
            background_image: ''
            background_color: rgba('#637075')
            on_release: app.root.current = 'track'
        MenuButton:
            text: 'Enter PESS'
            height: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
            background_image: ''
            background_color: rgba('#637075')
            on_release: app.root.current = 'pess'
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color: 
                    rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 1
        Label:
            id: time
            text: ''
            markup: True

<PessQuestions>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        ActionBar:
            height: self.minimum_height + dp(50)
            size_hint_y: None
            background_image: ''
            background_color: rgba('#ffffff') # rgba('#0B3242')
            ActionView:
                ActionPrevious:
                    title: '[b]PESS[/b]'
                    font_size: '17dp'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    markup: True
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'track'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'SEND'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').send(root) # if .send() function is on another class outside of 'class PessQuestions' use the .get_screen() to locate the right screen class
                    #on_release: app.root.send()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'TRACKER'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'track'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'HOME'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: dp(10)
            spacing: dp(12)
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}

            TextInput:
                id: phy_text
                hint_text: 'Physical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: emo_text
                hint_text: 'Emotional'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: spi_text
                hint_text: 'Spiritual'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: sex_text
                hint_text: 'Sexual'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: comment
                hint_text: 'Leave a comment'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(100)

            MenuButton:
                id: save_pess
                text: 'Save PESS'
                height: dp(60)
                size_hint_y: None
                background_image: ''
                on_press: self.text = 'SAVED!'
                on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').savePESS(root)

            MenuButton2:
                text: 'Clear PESS'
                height: dp(60)
                size_hint_y: None
                background_image: ''
                on_press: root.ids.save_pess.text = 'Save PESS'
                on_release: root.resetPESS()

            MenuButton:
                text: 'Send Report'
                color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                height: dp(60)
                size_hint_y: None
                background_image: ''
                on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').send(root) # if .send() function is on another class outside of 'class PessQuestions' use the .get_screen() to locate the right screen class
                #on_release: app.root.send()

            Label:
                canvas.before:
                    Color: 
                        rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 1

            Label:
                text: '[b]Physical, Emotional, Spiritual, Sexual[/b] | These principles when lived with a full purpose of heart will invite the Holy Ghost into your lives.'
                markup: True
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Label:
                id: pess_date
                text: ''
                markup: True

            Label:
                canvas.before:
                    Color: 
                        rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 1

            # Label & Checkbox creation | for selecting email address
            Label:
                text: "EMAIL"
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            ScrollView:
                BoxLayout:
                    id: info
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: dp(5)
                    spacing: dp(7)
                    #size_hint_y: None
                    #height: self.minimum_height + dp(50)
            TextInput:
                id: name
                hint_text: 'Name'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id: address
                hint_text: 'Email Address'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height + dp(7)
                multiline: False
            MenuButton:
                id: save_email
                text: 'Save Email'
                height: dp(60)
                size_hint_y: None
                background_image: ''
                on_release: root.saveEmails()


<Checkboxes>:
    CheckBox:
        group: 'emails'
        color: .294, .761, .623
        on_active: root.on_checkbox_Active(self, self.active)
        #on_active: app.root.get_screen('pess').on_checkbox_Active(self, self.active)
        size_hint_x: .50
    Label:
        id: who_name
        text: ''
        text_size: self.width, None
        halign: 'left'
    Label:
        id: who_email
        text: ''
        text_size: self.width, None
        halign: 'left'
    Button:
        text: '[b]X[/b]'
        markup: True
        size_hint_x: None
        width: dp(20)
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('pess').delete_email(root)

<Trackers>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ActionBar:
            height: self.minimum_height + dp(50)
            size_hint_y: None
            background_image: ''
            background_color: rgba('#ffffff') #rgba('#0B3242')
            ActionView:
                ActionPrevious:
                    title: '[b]TRACKERS[/b]'
                    font_size: '17dp'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    markup: True
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'pess'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'RESET'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: root.reset_pop()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'PESS'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'pess'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'HOME'
                    color: rgba('#AFB7BA')
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                id: track
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: dp(10)
                spacing: dp(15)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(100)
            Button:
                text: '+'
                font_size: '56dp'
                size_hint_y: None
                background_image: ''
                background_color: (0,0,0,0)
                on_release: root.addWidget()

        #BoxLayout:
            #FloatButton:
            #    pos_hint_x: None
            #    pos_hint_y: None
            #    on_release: root.addWidget()

<Tracker>:
    count_add: count_add
    name: name
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 130

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos[0] + self.height/2, self.pos[1]
            size: self.size[0] - self.height, self.height
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1]
            size: self.height, self.height
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos[0] + self.width - self.height, self.pos[1]
            size: self.height, self.height

    TrackerButton:
        text: '[b]X[/b]'
        markup: True
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').delete_storage(root)

    Label:
        id: name
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 1

    TrackerButton:
        id: label
        font_size: '16dp'
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').change_name(root)

    TrackerButton:
        id: count_add
        font_size: '16dp'
        text: '0'
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').add_num(root)

    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: (1,1,1,.7)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 1

    TrackerButton:
        text: '[b]-[/b]'
        font_size: '24dp'
        markup: True
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 120
        on_release: app.root.get_screen('track').subtract_num(root)
```

I had my code running really well, but all of the email sending information was hardcoded. I wanted to give the user options to input an email address and send it to that address.

I added the class Checkboxes which get's created every time I add a name and email address and hit the "Save Email" It's grouped so they are radio buttons.

I can't seem to connect the email address to my send function on the class Trackers... I hope all of this makes some sense. I might be overly complicating things for myself. I could use some help please. Thank you.

[image: Tracker Screen]

[image: Pess Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came across this question and since I am short on time I wont be able to help you completely. If you ever want to access widgets inside and outside of your class screens you need to have a shared parent for the both of them. In your main py file you can have something like this defined.

```
class MainInterface(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainInterface, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeWindow(Screen):
    ...
    
class TrackerWindow(Screen):
    ...
    
sm = WindowManager()
screens = [HomeWindow(name="Home"), TrackerWindow(name="TrackerWindow")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)
    
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MainInterface()
        return root
```

The way you use your kv file from now on will be different from what you are used to. Your kv file can look something like this. I'll be using different example uses for one button to save time for myself.

```
<MainInterface>:
    WindowManager:
        id: screenmanager
        HomeWindow:
            id: homewindow
            ...
            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":1}
                size_hint: 0.125, 0.1
                text: "Some Stuff"
                font_size: (root.width**1 + root.height**1) / 10**2
                on_release:
                    root.ids['trackerwindow'].send(YourData)
                    root.ids['homewindow'].access_user_inputs(self.parent.user_inputs)
                    root.ids['screenmanager'].transition.direction = "left"
                    root.ids['screenmanager'].current="TrackerWindow"
        TrackerWindow:
            id: trackerwindow
            ...
```

notice how on the homescreen button to get information from its own screen you can't just use root.access_user_inputs(root.user_inputs) you created a parent tree so you use self.parent if you want to access a function from your windowmanager you would do a similar set up but use self.parent.parent. I hope this helps and if you have questions please ask and I'll be able to further help you later.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I had moved on to another idea for the App but I would love to revisit this. I really appreciate it. I've learned a lot since this i think I should be able with your help above to implement it. :)